# Use feof twice on same file stream

Tags: c

I'm counting the number of lines in a file using `feof` as you see below.  After that finishes, I need to loop line by line through the same file and do another operation that depends on knowing the number of lines. However, `while (!feof(f))` won't run a second time on the same file stream. Is there a way to reset the `f` back to the beginning so I can loop through it again?

```
 while (!feof(f))
  {
    ch = fgetc(f);
    if(ch == '\n')
    {
      lines++;
    }

  }

  while (!feof(f))
  {
    //need to do an operation that depends on knowing number of lines from first feof but this loop doesn't run because f is at the end

  }
```

Comment: Do you know `rewind()` in `stdio`? Also please see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You can't use `feof()` on file descriptors; `feof()` is for testing file streams, represented by a `FILE *` variable.  A file descriptor is a small integer, obtained from `open()` and related functions, and used with `read()`, `write()`, `lseek()`, `close()` etc.  Please do not misuse 'descriptor' when you mean 'stream'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call you seek is `fseek`.

Specifically this will set the file position back to the start of the file:

```
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Note that this can fail (for instance if the file isn't a normal file but a socket or some such) so you'd want to check its return value and, if it returns -1, `errno`.

Comment: [`rewind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fes6c2yd.aspx) says *"unlike `fseek`, `rewind` clears the error indicators for the stream as well as the end-of-file indicator"*.

Comment: You can also use `clearerr` in conjunction with `fseek` to get the same effect with the added bonus that you'll get clear error reporting. `rewind` would require you to zero out `errno` first.

Comment: @Benno: nothing in the standard C or POSIX libraries ever sets `errno` to zero.  The end-of-file indicator and the error indicator for a file stream are separate from `errno` — almost wholly unrelated to it.

Comment: I meant that your program would have to explicitly set `errno` to zero before calling `rewind` if you intended to properly error check. Quoting the FreeBSD man page:

`Since rewind() does not return a value, an application wishing to detect errors should clear errno, then call rewind(), and if errno is non-zero, assume an error has occurred.`